# Laravel: Custom Middleware is applying on each route

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-middleware

I created a middleware as:

```
use Closure;
use Gate;
class ACLMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Gate::denies('access-post')) {
            abort(403,'Not allowed!!!');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And then define in route as:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth','acl'], function () {

    Route::resource('post', 'PostController');
   ...
```

When I run this.. it's applying on all routes, even on `/`. Why is like that?

**Kernel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\ACLMiddleware::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth'       => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest'      => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'acl'        => \App\Http\Middleware\ACLMiddleware::class,
    ];
}
```

Comment: what does your `App\Http\Kernel.php` file look like?

Comment: @tam Question updated

Comment: does 'auth' run on every request or just 'acl'?

Comment: Found the issue, instead of array I set middleware as strings; forgot to add `[]`. Now it works!!

Comment: yup beat me to it. the small things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your middleware are registered in `App\Http\Kernel.php`.

The array:

```
protected $middleware = ['...'];
```

defines the middleware that should be run on every http request. In your case you need to remove `\App\Http\Middleware\ACLMiddleware::class` if you don't want it run on every request.

The array:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = ['...'];
```

defines the middleware that will only be applied where you specify. This is where your definitions belong.

Comment: I removed but now it is not being called on route either.

Comment: Do I need to make changes the way I am setting a middleware route?

Answer (score 0):

You need to link your middleware with your route using the MW class name like : `Route::post('route', 'Controller@index')->middleware(Authorize::class);`